# wkhtmltopdf pass cyrillic value to --header parameter

Tags: encoding, cmd, wkhtmltopdf, cyrillic

I am using wkhtmltopdf.exe command line tool to render HTML into PDF.

I try to generate PDF with custom header using cyrillic symbols. So I have cmd command like this:

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe --header-center "Заказ в Австралию — Test" http://localhost/MyPage c:/1.pdf
```

The issue is that in generated PDF the header looks like this: "?????? ? ??????? - Test"

I tried to add parameter `--encoding utf-8` but this not worked for me

Note that my pc is running Windows with the only installed English (US) system locale.

Is there any thoughts how to solve this issue without installing any other system locale?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? 7, 8, 8.1, 10?

Comment: I am using Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: What is the active codepage? What is the output of the `chcp` command?

Comment: Current is 437 - United States. I Tried to change on 866 (Russian), on UTF-8 and some others. There was no difference in the output PDF header.

Comment: Does your system have a font capable of rendering Cyrillics? Looks like `wkhtmltopdf` is falling to back to the default font, which doesn't support non-Latin characters.

Comment: Try adding <meta charset="UTF-8"> in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic but hope my solution will help someone. Here is what helped me (used good clue from lit comment above) :

1. created .bat file with text like this:
   chcp 65001
   C:\data\wkhtmltopdf.exe --footer-font-size "10" --footer-center "Сторінка [page] з [topage]" file:///C:\data\12345.html C:\data\12345.pdf
2. for my server side solution I called  ProcessStartInfo for FileName="cmd" and Arguments= "/c "+batchfile
   This did the job.
   BUT - you still need to make sure that server is switched to your language for non-Unicode chars.